# Why does Iterator::all need the iterator to be mutable?

Tags: iterator, rust

I was using an iterator on a `String`'s characters:

```
pub fn is_yelling(message: &str) -> bool {
    let letters = message.chars().filter(|c| c.is_alphabetic());
    message.chars().any(|c| c.is_alphabetic()) && letters.all(|c| c.is_uppercase())
}
```

This raises a compilation error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable local variable `letters` as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:3:51
  |
2 |     let letters = message.chars().filter(|c| c.is_alphabetic());
  |         ------- consider changing this to `mut letters`
3 |     message.chars().any(|c| c.is_alphabetic()) && letters.all(|c| c.is_uppercase())
  |                                                   ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

When I make `letters` mutable everything runs smoothly.

I do not understand why this necessary. The `all` method should not have to alter the the iterator. Like `map` or `filter`, which take `self` and not `mut self` as an argument.

My [reference for `map` / `filter` / `all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

I saw [an issue on the matter](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22617), but no explanation was given.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterating *anything* requires mutating the iterator because [`Iterator::next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) takes `&mut self`. Checking all the values in the iterator requires iteration, therefore `Iterator::all` (and many similar methods) requires `&mut self` as well.

> The `all` method should not have to alter the the iterator.

I am very interested to hear how you propose to check every value in an iterator *without* calling `next`.

> Like `map` or `filter`

These methods return a new iterator, they do not call `next`. That being said, they could if they wanted because...

> which take `self` and not `mut self` as an argument.

Mutability is a property of the owner of a variable. These two functions are equivalent:

```
fn example(mut a: String) {}
```

```
fn example(a: String) {
    let mut a = a;
}
```

Importantly, both look the same in the generated documentation — neither have `mut` in the signature. This is because it doesn't matter to the caller.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. I suspected it was linked to the call to Iterator::next, but couldn't wrap my head around the map/filter case.

Answer (score 5):

The iterator methods `all` and `any` take a mutable reference because they will be modifying the iterator by consuming its elements (note that `next()` also requires `&mut self`, since it inherently modifies the state of the iterator). In addition, the methods are short-circuiting, and do not necessarily consume all elements of the iterator. This means that the methods can give the iterator back to the caller, thus being able to continue consuming from it if so is desired.

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 5];
let mut it = x.into_iter();
assert!(it.any(|x| x > 1));
assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(5));
```

`map` or `filter` work differently, because they are iterator *adaptors*. Once invoked, the returned adaptor value will own the underlying iterator, and thus requires `self` to be moved. Values do not have to be bound to a mutable variable to be moved to another scope, even if they are modified later on in that context.